# Excel SUMIFS() Statement

Tags: excel

I am looking to create a function that will use either SUMIFS() or something else that would acomplish the following on worksheet2 (w2):

```
A    B  C
RED  5  CAT
RED  7  CAT
BLUE 8  DOG
RED  2  DOG
```

such that all the values containing both CAT and RED are summed together, excluding all other values, but between worksheets.

So worksheet one would display all of these combinations. What I have right now is `=sumifs(w2!b2:b4,w2!a2:a4,red,w2!c2:c4,cat)` the function works on the same worksheet, but not across. Even with indexing the issue, `=index(w2!a2:c4,sumifs(w2!b2:b4,w2!a2:a4,red,w2!c2:c4,cat))` I cannot get a value.

Comment: I'm not clear on the reason for separate worksheets? What's the non `w2` worksheet doing?  Also, you do need to put quotes around `red`, `cat`, etc. i.e. `...a2:a4,"red",...`

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C4="CAT")*(A1:A4="RED")*(B1:B4))
```

[image]

If you have more than one worksheet, then make a sum for each sheet and then add them up.